# How do I calculate the most profit-dense combination in the most efficient way?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, combinations, dynamic-programming

I have a combinations problem that's bothering me.  I'd like someone to give me their thoughts and point out if I'm missing some obvious solution that I may have overlooked.

Let's say that there is a shop that buys all of its supplies from one supplier.  The supplier has a list of items for sale.  Each item has the following attributes:

```
size, cost, quantity, m, b
```

`m` and `b` are constants in the following equation:

```
sales = m * (price) + b
```

This line slopes downward.  The equation tells me how many of that item I will be able to sell if I charge that particular price. Each item has its own m and b values.

Let's say that the shop has limited storage space, and limited funds. The shop wants to fill its warehouse with the most profit-dense items possible.

(By the way, profit density = profit/size. I'm defining that profit density be only with regard to the items size.  I could work with the density with regard to size *and* cost, but to do that I'd have to know the cost of warehouse space.  That's not a number I know currently, so I'm just going to use size.)

The profit density of items drops the more you buy (see below.)

If I flip the line equation, I can see what price I'd have to charge to sell some given amount of the item in some given period of time.

```
price = (sales-b)/m
```

So if I buy n items and wanted to sell all of them, I'd have to charge

```
price = (n-b)/m
```

The revenue from this would be

```
price*n = n*(n-b)/m
```

The profit would be

```
price*n-n*cost = n*(n-b)/m - n*cost
```

and the profit-density would be

```
(n*(n-b)/m - n*cost)/(n*size)
```

or, equivalently

```
((n-b)/m - cost)/size
```

So let's say I have a table containing every available item, and each item's profit-density.

The question is, how many of each item do I buy in order to maximise the amount of money that the shop makes?

One possibility is to generate every possible combination of items within the bounds of cost and space, and choose the combo with the highest profitability.  In a list of 1000 items, this takes too long.  (I tried this and it took 17 seconds for a list of 1000.  Horrible.)

Another option I tried (on paper) was to take the top two most profitable items on the list.  Let's call the most profitable item A, the 2nd-most profitable item B, and the 3rd-most profitable item C.  I buy as many of item A as I can until it's less profitable than item B.  Then I repeat this process using B and C, for every item in the list.

It might be the case however, that after buying item B, item A is again the most profitable item, more so than C. So this would involve hopping from the current most profitable item to the next until the resources are exhausted.  I could do this, but it seems like an ugly way to do it.

I considered dynamic programming, but since the profit-densities of the items change depending on the amount you buy, I couldn't come up with a resolution for this.

I've considered multiple-linear regression, and by 'consider' I mean I've said to myself "is multi-linear regression an option?" and then done nothing with it.

My spidey-sense tells me that there's a far more obvious method staring me in the face, but I'm not seeing it.  Please help me kick myself and facepalm at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can treat this as a dynamic programming exercise, to make the best use of a limited resource.

As a simple example, consider just satisfying the constraint on space and ignoring that on cost. Then you want to find the items that generate the most profit for the available space. Choose units so that expressing the space used as an integer is reasonable, and then, for i = 1 to number of items, work out, for each integer value of space up to the limit, the selection of the first i items that gives the most return for that amount of space. As usual, you can work out the answers for i+1 from the answers for i: for each value from 0 up to the limit on space just consider all possible quantities of the i+1th item up to that amount of space, and work out the combined return from using that quantity of the item and then using the remaining space according to the answers you have already worked out for the first i items. When i reaches the total number of items you will be working out the best possible return for the problem you actually want to solve.

If you have constraints for both space and cost, then the state of the dynamic program is not the single variable (space) but a pair of variables (space, cost) but you can still solve it, although with more work. Consider all possible values of (space, cost) from (0, 0) up to the actual constraints - you have a 2-dimensional table of returns to compute instead of a single set of values from 0 to max-space. But you can still work from i=1 to N, computing the highest possible return for the first i items for each limit of (space, cost) and using the answers for i to compute the answers for i+1.

Answer (score 1):

If you treat this as a simple exercise in multivariate optimization, where the controllable variables are the quantities bought, then you are optimizing a quadratic function subject to a linear constraint.

If you use a Lagrange multiplier and differentiate then you get a linear equation for each quantity variable involving itself and the Lagrange multiplier as the only unknowns, and the constraint gives you a single linear equation involving all of the quantities. So write each quantity as a linear function of the Lagrange multiplier and substitute into the constraint equation to get a linear equation in the Lagrange multiplier. Solve this and then plug the Lagrange multiplier into the simpler equations to get the quantities.

This gives you a solution if you are allowed to buy fractional and negative quantities of things if required. Clearly you are not, but you might hope that nothing is very negative and you can round the non-integer quantities to get a reasonable answer. If this isn't good enough for you, you could use it as a basis for branch and bound. If you make an assumption on the value of one of the quantities and solve for the others in this way, you get an upper bound on the possible best answer - the profit predicted neglecting real world constraints on non-negativity and integer values will always be at least the profit earned if you have to comply with these constraints.